# Cannot resolve method getYouTubeService()

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I've imported the correct gradle items...and I can use a "Youtube" object, but cannot access the method described in their [own API docs?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/delete)

### [image]

> Cannot resolve method getYouTubeService()

```
  YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            //example
            parameters.put("id", "theid");

            YouTube.Subscriptions.Delete subscriptionsDeleteRequest = youtube.subscriptions().delete(parameters.get("id").toString());
            subscriptionsDeleteRequest.execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

**Gradle:**

```
//youtube api
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev205-1.24.1'
// Dependency for Google Sign-In
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

// Dependencies for the REST API example
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev139-1.22.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use as below with `Credentials` to get `YouTube` instance:

```
new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
```

Reference: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Quickstart.java